# No matching Function call with arguments that match the call

Tags: c++

```
Chemical_Compound::Chemical_Compound(Element &a)
{
    Elements.push_back(a);
}
```

This is my constructor

Prototype:

```
     Chemical_Compound(Element & a);
```

Now, here is where I try to use the constructor within another class and it's giving me problems

```
      Product_b(a);
```

Which is defined in the header as

```
       Chemical_Compound Product_b;
       Element a;
```

So, I'm really confused as to why I'm getting an error since the arguments match up and even if I remove the & it still gives me an error ,thanks!

I'm using QT editor

```
 /home/CENCORED/Code/cpp/Chem_Framework/reaction.cpp:23: error: no match for call to '(Chemical_Compound) (Element&)'
 Product_b(a);
            ^
```

Comment: Print the full error message

Comment: I think you meant: `Element a; Chemical_Compound Product_b(a);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor is called at construction only.

What is happening is that at:

```
Chemical_Compound Product_b;
```

you are calling the default constructor generated by the compiler which takes no argument.

Now when you try

```
Product_b(a);
```

Makes nosense as the compiler is telling you.

This would work:

```
Element a;
Chemical_Compound Product_b(a);
```

Comment: So, declaring the object in the header means that I called it? I'm not calling it multiple times I'm just initializing it once in a function.So, it goes---> declare object in the header ---> initialize object with a constructor in .cpp file.

Comment: You creating the object in the header.

Answer (score 1):

For a start this

```
Chemical_Compound Product_b;
Element a;
```

Should not be in a header.

But also should be

```
   Element a;
   Chemical_Compound Product_b(a);
```

Comment: I thought the act of declaring was different from initializing, alright I understand what I did wrong now. So, are you saying for good practice one should only declare class specific variables in the header? Or can you elaborate more on why it should not be in header?

Comment: You are not declaring those but creating them¬